# How to sort/filter a list in the same way you sort a database result

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, lambda

I am currently coding with .net core 5 preview 3 and I am having an issue with filtering a list of best matched customers.

1. Given these two different code samples how come they produce different results?
2. How can I fix the second sample to return the same results as the first sample?

#### Sample One (this works)

```
//This properly gives the top 10 best matches from the database
using (var context = new CustomerContext(_contextOptions))
{
    customers = await context.vCustomer.Where(c => c.Account_Number__c.Contains(searchTerm))
                    .Select(c => new
                    {
                        vCustomer = c,
                        MatchEvaluator = searchTerm.Contains(c.Account_Number__c)
                    })
                    .OrderByDescending(c => c.MatchEvaluator)
                    .Select(c => new CustomerModel
                    {
                        CustomerId = c.vCustomer.Account_Number__c,
                        CustomerName = c.vCustomer.Name
                    })
                    .Take(10)
                    .ToListAsync();
}
```

**Customer Id Results from sample one (these are the best results)**

- 247
- 2470
- 247105
- 247109
- 247110
- 247111
- 247112
- 247113
- 247116
- 247117

#### Sample Two (This doesn't work the same even though its the same code)

```
//this take all customers from database and puts them in a list so they can be cached and sorted on later.
List<CustomerModel> customers = new List<CustomerModel>();
using (var context = new CustomerContext(_contextOptions))
{
    customers = await context.vCustomer
                    .Select(c => new CustomerModel
                    {
                        CustomerId = c.Account_Number__c,
                        CustomerName = c.Name
                    })
                    .ToListAsync();
}

//This does not properly gives the top 10 best matches from the list that was generated from the database
List<CustomerModel> bestMatchedCustomers = await Task.FromResult(
    customers.Where(c => c.CustomerId.Contains(searchTerm))
                    .Select(c => new
                    {
                        Customer = c,
                        MatchEvaluator = searchTerm.Contains(c.CustomerId)
                    })
                    .OrderByDescending(c => c.MatchEvaluator)
                    .Select(c => new CustomerModel
                    {
                        CustomerId = c.Customer.CustomerId,
                        CustomerName = c.Customer.CustomerName
                    })
                    .Take(10)
                    .ToList()
);
```

**Customer Id Results from sample two**

- 247
- 1065247
- 247610
- 32470
- 324795
- 624749
- 762471
- 271247
- 247840
- 724732

Comment: Should match evaluator be `StartsWith()`? Surely as it stands match evaluator is only going to be 1 for a single result

Comment: Does sql profiler show some hint when comparing two sql queries?

Comment: @TomasPaul the first sample uses the database for the result and it sorts properly, the second sample just loads all customers into a list and then I try to do the same type of sorting/filtering on the list instead.

Comment: @the.Doc I don't think `StartsWith()` would work because if my search term was `610` I may not have a customer who starts with `610` but the best match could be `0610`

Comment: How does `searchTerm.Contains(c.Account_Number__c)' evaluate to 1 in that example?

Comment: @the.Doc its basically `if searchTerm.Contains(c.Account_Number__c) == 1` which is true or `if searchTerm.Contains(c.Account_Number__c) == 1` which is false, it could honestly just be simplified to `searchTerm.Contains(c.Account_Number__c)` which returns true or false anyway. I edited my question and removed it, seems it might be misleading peeps. I tested in code and it works the same way either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ordering by the `MatchEvaluator` value which is either 1 or 0.

If I understood correctly what you want to do is first order by the `MatchEvaluator` and then by the `CustomerId`:

```
List<CustomerModel> bestMatchedCustomers = 
    await Task.FromResult(
        customers.Where(c => c.CustomerId.Contains(searchTerm))
                 .OrderBy(c => c.CustomerId.IndexOf(searchTerm))
                 .ThenBy(c => c.CustomerId)
                 .Select(c => new CustomerModel
                 {
                     CustomerId = c.Customer.CustomerId,
                     CustomerName = c.Customer.CustomerId
                 })
                 .Take(10)
                 .ToList()
);
```

Comment: 1 : 0 is true or false. The MatchEvaluator returns true or false if the searchTerm contains the customerId. But for grins and giggles I gave your solution a try anyway and VS is underlining it with an error because customerId is a string, the customer id isn't always a series of numbers, it could also contains letters, but what the heck lets give it a try, I converted to an int and it still didn't sort properly and actually it just sorted in the same way as it did previously.

Comment: yes, it's 1 or 0 for the comparer which will not care about the CustomerId's value. If it see them both as 1 for example, it explains how two Ids can be in the reverse order with each other- since the comparer will sort them arbitrarily as 1s

Comment: see updated answer, and the orderby should work with strings too, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.6

Comment: With that exact code I am getting a completely different sort now, still not what I am seeing from sample one. The Id's in order: `9247, 8247, 772478, 762473, 762471, 751247, 742473, 732479, 732476, 724732` As you can see this sort is not the best match. I have tried many variations of my filter before I asked for help. I think the final solution is going to be much different than this answer but thank you for trying.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by best match here. Do you mean ordered by the id as a number?
If yes then use:
`.OrderByDescending(c => int.Parse(c.CustomerId))`
and it should be descending by number value. Currently it uses strings so it's lexicographic

Comment: The best match is the best match to the search term, see sample one and it's results. The results I need from my list shown in sample two should be the same results I get from sample one. The results should be the best match to say a searchTerm of `247`, the best match is of course `247`, the second best match would be `2470` as shown in sample one results.

Comment: So `247` is what I use as searchTerm in this example but I may have another searchTerm of `610`, I don't have any customers who startWith `610` but I do have customers who contain `610`, in this case `610` would result in `0610` as being the best match.

Comment: so it means you want to search results based on the location of the searchTerm in the ID and then sort lexicographically no? I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Still no go, the best match result it gave me was `1091247` but it should have given `247` first, as a matter of fact `247` wasn't even in the top 10 list. Basically if you know SQL and can re-purpose the following sql in your table, you can see what it means to have the best result in a list: `SELECT [Account_Number]
  FROM [ops].[Customer]
  where Account_Number LIKE '%247%'
  order by CHARINDEX('247', Account_Number, 1), Account_Number
` The results from sample one also clearly explains how I want my result to look from the list.

Comment: try to reverse the order, using `OrderBy` instead of `OrderByDescending` in my answer. Also updated it

Comment: I tried that previously and I still didn't get the right results. The closest I have come to getting it right is by using the MatchEvaluator. I was even just trying some of what you have shown in conjunction and I still am not getting the same results as I do in sample 1. I don't understand why sample one does exactly what I want but I can't get the same results from a list.

Comment: the code in the answer should now give you the same results as Sample 1.
did you try to run it? and if so - which result wasn't ordered correctly?

Comment: Looks like that worked, its throwing an extra id in there that doesn't show up in the results of sample one but it looks like it may be a better match anyway. Thank you for continually trying. I had previously tried order by ascending but without the `IndexOf`and that did the trick.

Comment: I am still confused as to why my code worked great against a data result but not the same against a list.

Comment: as Caius Jard answered- it's because in the db it's already ordered while in the list it's not

Answer (score 2):

You asked "why are they different" and for this you need to appreciate that databases have a optimizer that looks at the query being run and changes its data access strategy according to various things like how many records are being selected, whether indexes apply, what sorting is requested etc

One of your queries selects all the database table into the client side list and then uses the list to do the filter and sort, the other uses the database to do the filter and the sort. To a database these will be very different things; hitting a table you likely get the rows out in the order they're stored on disk, which could be random. Using a filter you might see the database using some indexing strategy where it includes/discounts a large number of rows based on an index, or it might even use the index to retrieve the requested data. How it then sorts the ties, if it does, might be completely different to how the client side list sorts ties (does nothing with them actually). Either way, the important point is the database is planning and executing your two different queries differently. It sees different queries because your second version runs the query without a where or order by

When you couple this up with your sort operation being on a column that is incredibly cardinality (how unique the values in the column are) i.e.  your lead result, the one where the record equals the search term, is 1 and EVERYTHING else is 0. This means that one record bubbles to the top then the rest of the records are free to be sorted however the system doing the sorting likes, and then you take a subset of them

..hence why one looks like X and the other like Y

If you didn't take the subset the two datasets would be in different orders but everything in set 1 would be in set 2 somewhere... it's just that one set is like 1 3 5 7 2 4 6, the other is like 1 7 6 5 4 3 2, you're taking the first three results and asking "why is 1 3 5 different to 1 7 6"

---

In terms of your code, I think I would have just done something simple that also sorts in a stable fashion (rows in same order because there is no ambiguity/ties) like:

```
await context.vCustomer
  .Where(c => c.Account_Number__c.Contains(searchTerm))
  .OrderBy(c => c.Account_Number__c.Length)
  .ThenBy(c => c.Account_Number__c) //stable, if unique
  .Take(10)
  .Select(c => new CustomerModel
    {
      CustomerId = c.vCustomer.Account_Number__c,
      CustomerName = c.vCustomer.Name
    }
  )
  .ToListAsync();
```

If you sort the results by their length in chars then 247 is better match than 2470, which is better than 24711 or 12471 etc

"Contains" can be quite performance penalising; perhaps consider StartsWith; theoretically at least, an index could still be used for that

ps: calling your var a MatchEvaluator makes things really confusing for people who know regex well btw

Comment: Wow, thank you. you answered both of the questions and very informatively. I got the match evaluator code from another stack overflow answer when I was trying to figure out the linq equivalent to using: `SELECT [Account_Number] FROM [ops].[Customer] where Account_Number LIKE '%247%' order by CHARINDEX('247', Account_Number, 1), Account_Number` on my database. I also just learned I could have maybe done something like `SqlFunctions.CharIndex(...)`.

Comment: I also didn't like using `startsWith` because in some case a `searchTerm` may not be something that a `customerId` starts with like for instance say a `searchTerm` was `610` but the best matched account number would be `10610`.

Comment: Indeed, it's one of those trade offs - it's a lot faster to determine if a string starts with something than if it contains something.. if you need Contains, use Contains.. if you can get away with starts with, give it a go!